# How to connect a MySQL Docker Container to a Spring Boot Application running locally

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
add target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

FROM mysql:8.0.32

ENV MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0 \
    MYSQL_PORT=3307 \
    MYSQL_DATABASE=Countries \
    MYSQL_USER=root \
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=root \
    MYSQL_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    

# Start Spring Boot application
CMD java -jar app.jar \
    --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}/${MYSQL_DATABASE} \
    --spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER} \
    --spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} \
    --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${MYSQL_DRIVER}
```

This is the content of my Dockerfile in my spring boot project.
When I run "mvn clean packages" command in terminal, I get the following errors. What do you recommend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuwJc.png)

```
2023-04-20T15:28:26.491+03:00  WARN 15852 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.Generion encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.sisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabath resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' pth name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/auration$Tomcat.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSou
threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-04-20T15:28:26.503+03:00  INFO 15852 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.Conditi

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re enabled.
2023-04-20T15:28:26.538+03:00 ERROR 15852 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingF

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedd
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on t
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile youles are currently active).




============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    None


Negative matches:
-----------------

    None


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1FBd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1x0O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ9Mg.png)

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.857 s srestapi.CountriesRestApiApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergetClass = com.hum.countriesrestapi.CountriesRestApiApplicationTests, locations = stapi.CountriesRestApiApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfil [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBo
contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterringframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$Duplica660, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.nt.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5824a83d, org.springframework.boot.test.autbservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1,oconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boWebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@26d9b808, org.springframework.boot.ion@118ad067], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springfootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: ErrurceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframewoaSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed throseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined iramework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Failed tdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: ver class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creatiined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSouiled to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dasage: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instal.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed ss
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$Datad to determine a suitable driver class

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   CountriesRestApiApplicationTests.contextLoads ┬╗ IllegalState Failed t
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.050 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-20T15:28:27+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 on project countries-rest-api: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Humeyra\Desktop\GITHUB\sonbirdeneme\CountriesSpringBootProject\target\surefire-reports for 
the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I want to connect my mysql container in Docker to my java spring boot project in this local. But I was not able to create the correct dockerfile.

Comment: HI, welcome to SO.  Please don't paste images of text.  Copy the text itself and paste into the question so we can read it.